# click not working if parsed through reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written a code and need the truncate the text at first it is rendered and then on click of read more the full text should be shown. but the click is not working when clicked

```js
class DC extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    _parseText(text, flag) {
      if (text.length > 200 && flag === true) {
        return text.substr(0, 200) + ' <a onClick={this._parseText(text,false)}>Read More...</a>';
      } else {
        return text;
      }
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
          <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:this._parseText('Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.', true)}}></p>)
}
}
        
ReactDOM.render(<DC/>, document.getElementById('test'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: updated a running script

Comment: You want to do `render() { return (<p>{{text}}{{ renderReadMore() }}</p>)}`, and inside the `renderReadMore` method you return `null` if condition is not met ^^

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var _parseText=(text, flag)=> {
      console.log(flag)
      if (text.length > 200 && flag == true) {
        return text.substr(0, 200) + ' <a onClick={_parseText(text,false)}>Read More...</a>';
      } else {
        return text;
      }
    }

class DC extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }


    render() {
        return ( 
          <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:_parseText('Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.', true)}}></p>)
}
}
        
ReactDOM.render(<DC/>, document.getElementById('test'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Put the function outside the component and call it without this.

Comment: on mine its saying _parseText is not defined